# hide div the link is clicked in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to hide the div that the link was clicked within, then display the results div in place of the artist div

```
<div class="artist">
  <a href="#" class="artist-link">click</a>
</div>
<div class="results"></div>

<div class="artist">
  <a href="#" class="artist-link">click</a>
</div>
<div class="results"></div>

<div class="artist">
  <a href="#" class="artist-link">click</a>
</div>
<div class="results"></div>
```

Once you click the link, it hides the .artist div that link was clicked within, then displays its respective results div.

Comment: where is your css and javascript?

Comment: yes, show your javascript and css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do like this http://jsfiddle.net/aGV7B/1/ :

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('div').hide().next().show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var $parent = $(this).parent();
    $parent.hide().next().show();
});
```

[**Demo Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/u7ZpZ/)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `closest(selector)` and `next(selector)` functions. The advantage of using selector is that you can change the markup (to some extent) without rendering your javascript code invalid.

```
$('.artist').click(function () {
    $(this).next('.results').fadeIn('fast').end().closest('.artist').fadeOut('fast');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use jQuery.

```
$('.artist-link').click( function(){
    $(this).parent().hide();
    $(this).parent().next().show();
} )
```

For more infos:
http://api.jquery.com/